# Forcing a View to the bottom right of View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, cs193p

I'm teaching myself SwiftUI by taking the 2020 version of Stanford's CS193p posted on YouTube.

I'd like to have a `ZStack` with a check box in the bottom right.  This code puts the check mark
right in the middle of the View.

```
ZStack {
    .... stuff ....
    Text("✓")
}
```

Much to my surprise, this code puts the check mark in the top left corner of the View.  (My mental model of `GeometryReader` is clearly wrong.)

```
ZStack {
   .... stuff ...
   GeometryReader { _ in Text("✓") }
}
```

I can't use `ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { ... }` as suggested in a different StackOverflow answer, as I want the alignment to apply only to the text, and not to anything else.

Is there any way to get the check mark on the bottom right?  I'm trying to avoid absolute offsets, since I want my code to work no matter what the size of the `ZStack` view.  Also, is there a good tutorial on layout so that I can figure out the answer to these questions myself?

[In case you're wondering.  I'm playing around with Homework Assignment 3.  I'm adding a "cheat mode" where if there is a matchingSet on the board, it marks them with a small check mark.]

Comment: Do you know the size of the largest subview in the ZStack? I have a solution using this info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
```

to Text.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's possible if you know the size of the `Text` and the largest subview in the `ZStack`.

In the example below I've used 40 as the `Text` width and 20 as the `Text` height, and 200 (square) for the largest `Color` subview. You can then calculate the subview offsets using relative offsets and layout guides.

This is useful if you don't want to expand the Text to fill the container like the above answer.

```
struct ColorsView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
      Color.red.frame(width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      alignment: .center)
      Text("Bye")
      Text("Hello").frame(width: 40, height: 20)
        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center, computeValue: { dimension in
          -60
        })
        .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center, computeValue: { dimension in
          -80
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I really was hoping that I wouldn't have to hard code numbers.  Back in InterfaceBuilder days, I could just pin a TextView to the bottom right of the enclosing container.